# If $f’(x)$ is not $0$ for all $x$, then either $f’(x)>0$ for all $x$ or $f’(x)<0$ for all $x$.

Tags: real-analysis

It is given that $I$ is an interval in $\Bbb{R}$. 
And $f: I\to \Bbb{R}$ is differentiable on $I$.

How do I show that if $f’(x)$ is not equal to $0$ for all $x$ in $I$,
Then either $f’(x)>0$ for all $x$ in $I$, or $f’(x)<0$ for all $x$ in $I$.

A hint is given to me that I will have to use Darboux’s theorem to prove this. However, I have no idea how to make use of the theorem.

Comment: well if $g:I\to \Bbb R$ is continuous then $g(I)=[\min_{x\in I}g(x),\max_{x\in I}g(x)]$

Comment: @Surb But $f'$ need not be continuous...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I know. Nevertheless, this is the idea. In the end you need refinement of this result.

Answer (score 7):

The derivative function has the [Intermediate Value Property due to Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)). Therefore, if it takes positive and negative values it takes all values in between, in particular zero.

Comment: Thank you so much! That is very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Let $J=[c,d] \subseteq I$. Let's asume that $0$ is between $f'(c)$ and $f'(d)$. By Darboux theorem we conclude that there exists $\theta \in [c,d]$ such that $f'(\theta)=0$, this is a contradiction because $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in I$ (and therefore for all $x \in J$).